# what is $E(|X|^2)$ given $X$ is uniformly distributed on $[-1,1]$

Tags: probability, statistics

We know that $E(|X|^2)= \mathrm{Var}(|X|) + {E(|X|)}^2$, where $E(|X|)=1/2 $ for sure. Then how to calculate $\mathrm{Var}(|X|)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [law of the unconscious statistician](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_unconscious_statistician) yield
$$
{\rm E}[|X|^2]={\rm E}[X^2]=\int_{-1}^1 x^2\,f_X(x)\,\mathrm dx,
$$
where $f_X$ is the density of $X$.

Another approach is to simply find the distribution of $|X|$. Clearly $|X|$ takes on the values between $0$ and $1$ and for $a\in(0,1)$ we have
$$
P(|X|\leq a)=P(-a\leq X\leq a)=F_X(a)-F_X(-a)=\frac{a+1}{2}-\frac{-a+1}{2}=\frac{2a}{2}=a.
$$

Which distribution does this correspond to?